# Django - dynamic model parameter value

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two simple models with ForeignKey relation, Category and Object let say (Object has FK attribute to Category) and in administration I need to assign value of another object attribute value base on the actually selected Category.

Example:

*I will create in Django Admin interface Category with attribute cat_name="A" and another Category with cat_name="B".
Now in the Object creation form I can select in the form "A" or "B" Category, and based on that selection I need to store in Object.description attribute something like "Selected category is B"*

I've tried several approaches but all ended on the fact that the instance of the Category object has to be somehow passed to the Object creation form.

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure, you are talking about the admin side not in your views.py, right?

Comment: Have you considered using the post_save (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save) signal?

Comment: Yep, so far I'm at admin site phase ;-)
Will check that Post save, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do this before saving you data by overriding the save function:

```
class ObjectModel(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(# details goes here)
    .....  # other fields goes here

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.category.name == 'A':
            self.description = ...
        elif self.category.name == 'B':
            .... # different behavior etc
        super(ObjectModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, finaly I have find acceptable solution. I'm creating the related object at the time of Category object is being saved and passing it's attribute to the object. Something like

```
class Category(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
      ...
      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
                Object.objects.create(name=self.name)
```

Only disadvantage I've noticed that Objects created this *automated way* has to have empty (if allowed) or *machine generated* attributed, but that's just a minor defect for me and I can do any updates via common administration form is needed.